# How to change position of data columns using regex in a CSV file using comma as separator?

Tags: python, regex, variables, multiple-columns

I am giving up with this, its almost due date. I enrolled to regex class this summer (biggest mistake of my life), and we have this topic (where we choose an old software and make updates to it), well I'm almost done with everything but, except this, I have a .txt document of database of monster attributes?

Anyways, the logic is each variable represent columns/keys and each column are separated by comma. And we need to delete/add/reposition the columns using any available tool (regex the only thing I know can help me? do you know anything? )

Here is the OLD form:

`ID,Name,JName,LV,HP,SP,EXP,JEXP,Range1,ATK1,ATK2,DEF,MDEF,STR,AGI,VIT,INT,DEX,LUK,Range2,Range3,Scale,Race,Element,Mode,Speed,ADelay,aMotion,dMotion,Drop1id,Drop1per,Drop2id,Drop2per,Drop3id,Drop3per,Drop4id,Drop4per,Drop5id,Drop5per,Drop6id,Drop6per,Drop7id,Drop7per,Drop8id,Drop8per,MEXP,ExpPer,MVP1id,MVP1per,MVP2id,MVP2per,MVP3id,MVP3per`

**First**, delete 7th column from the last (deleting all **ExpPer** entries):

Results to:
`ID,Name,JName,LV,HP,SP,EXP,JEXP,Range1,ATK1,ATK2,DEF,MDEF,STR,AGI,VIT,INT,DEX,LUK,Range2,Range3,Scale,Race,Element,Mode,Speed,ADelay,aMotion,dMotion,Drop1id,Drop1per,Drop2id,Drop2per,Drop3id,Drop3per,Drop4id,Drop4per,Drop5id,Drop5per,Drop6id,Drop6per,Drop7id,Drop7per,Drop8id,Drop8per,MEXP,MVP1id,MVP1per,MVP2id,MVP2per,MVP3id,MVP3per`

**Second**, duplicate **JName** column to next column:

Results to:
`ID,Name,JName,Jname,LV,HP,SP,EXP,JEXP,Range1,ATK1,ATK2,DEF,MDEF,STR,AGI,VIT,INT,DEX,LUK,Range2,Range3,Scale,Race,Element,Mode,Speed,ADelay,aMotion,dMotion,Drop1id,Drop1per,Drop2id,Drop2per,Drop3id,Drop3per,Drop4id,Drop4per,Drop5id,Drop5per,Drop6id,Drop6per,Drop7id,Drop7per,Drop8id,Drop8per,MEXP,MVP1id,MVP1per,MVP2id,MVP2per,MVP3id,MVP3per`

**Third**, pull the last 7 columns, put them starting to 31st column, i.e. from `...,dMotion,Drop1id,Drop1per,...` to `...,dMotion,MEXP,...,MVP3per,Drop1id,...`

Results to:
`ID,Name,JName,Jname,LV,HP,SP,EXP,JEXP,Range1,ATK1,ATK2,DEF,MDEF,STR,AGI,VIT,INT,DEX,LUK,Range2,Range3,Scale,Race,Element,Mode,Speed,ADelay,aMotion,dMotion,MEXP,MVP1id,MVP1per,MVP2id,MVP2per,MVP3id,MVP3per,Drop1id,Drop1per,Drop2id,Drop2per,Drop3id,Drop3per,Drop4id,Drop4per,Drop5id,Drop5per,Drop6id,Drop6per,Drop7id,Drop7per,Drop8id,Drop8per`

**Fourth,** Finally, add these columns to the last: **,0,0,DONE,1**:

Results to:
`ID,Name,JName,Jname,LV,HP,SP,EXP,JEXP,Range1,ATK1,ATK2,DEF,MDEF,STR,AGI,VIT,INT,DEX,LUK,Range2,Range3,Scale,Race,Element,Mode,Speed,ADelay,aMotion,dMotion,MEXP,MVP1id,MVP1per,MVP2id,MVP2per,MVP3id,MVP3per,Drop1id,Drop1per,Drop2id,Drop2per,Drop3id,Drop3per,Drop4id,Drop4per,Drop5id,Drop5per,Drop6id,Drop6per,Drop7id,Drop7per,Drop8id,Drop8per,0,0,DONE,1`

Hence, if I run whatever or how many regex search/replace tool,
the original:

`1052,ROCKER,Rocker,9,198,0,20,16,1,24,29,5,10,1,9,18,10,14,15,10,12,1,4,22,129,200,1864,864,540,940,5000,909,5500,2298,4,1402,80,520,10,752,5,703,3,4021,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`

would result to:

`1052,ROCKER,Rocker,Rocker,9,198,0,20,16,1,24,29,5,10,1,9,18,10,14,15,10,12,1,4,22,129,200,1864,864,540,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,940,5000,909,5500,2298,4,1402,80,520,10,752,5,703,3,4021,10,0,0,DONE,1`

Hope somebody can help me, there are 500+ monsters in this old database .txt file.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use regex? It seems like it'd be simpler to just split the string by the commas and manipulate the resulting list using regular string and list operations. Regex seems like overkill here.

Comment: @Michael0x2a sir, no. Regex is the only thing I know, I only need the resulting output. Do you know any tool? Would be very great. You are going to save my class.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't matter how you complete the task, you could maybe import the csv file into excel (or google spreadsheets, libreoffice calc, whatever), manipulate the columns there, then export the final product to csv again.

Comment: wait, i'm not familiar with the method, it is a .txt file. How do you do that? How to convert to csv?

Comment: Rename the file to end with .csv instead of .txt (csv stands for "comma separated values"). Open the file using a spreadsheet program such as excel -- it should allow you to import it. You can then manipulate the columns as usual (drag the columns around, delete them, copy, insert, etc). If you're not familiar with how to use excel, you'll probably find many tutorials online. You only really need a few basics to do what you're trying to do, so it shouldn't take long. Once you're done, save it in csv format, then rename the file to end in .txt again.

Comment: Thanks you saved my life! Yes I imported, set comma as delimiter. OMG. this is soooo good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Excel has a [Text Import Wizard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/text-import-wizard-HP010102244.aspx) to import data in any CSV format from any text file into an empty Excel worksheet. This wizard can be used for small CSV files to load the data, next delete/move/copy data columns and finally export/save the modified data again in CSV format into a file.

But the question was about reformatting the CSV file using a text editor with regular expression.

I used UltraEdit v21.20 with selecting Perl regular expression engine, but below should work with any text editor supporting Perl regular expressions. The regular expression search and replace strings should work also with Python.

**Important:**
The regular expressions below work only if CSV file does not contain commas in double quoted values.

**First**, delete 7th column from the last (deleting all **ExpPer** entries):

Search:   `,[^,\r\n]*?(,(?:[^,\r\n]*?,){5}[^,\r\n]*)$`
Replace: `\1`

**Second**, duplicate **JName** column to next column:

Search:   `^((?:[^,\r\n]*?,){2})([^,\r\n]*?,)`
Replace: `\1\2\2`

**Third**, pull the last 7 columns, put them starting to 31st column:

Search:   `^((?:[^,\r\n]*?,){30})((?:[^,\r\n]*?,){15}[^,]*?),((?:[^,\r\n]*?,){6}[^,\r\n]*)$`
Replace: `\1\3,\2`

**Fourth**, finally, add **,0,0,DONE,1** to the last:

Search:   `(.)$`
Replace: `\1,0,0,DONE,1`

But those 4 replaces can be done also with a single regular expression replace:

Search:   `^((?:[^,\r\n]*?,){2})([^,\r\n]*?,)((?:[^,\r\n]*?,){26})((?:[^,\r\n]*?,){16})([^,\r\n]*?,)[^,\r\n]*?,((?:[^,\r\n]*?,){5}[^,\r\n]*)$`
Replace: `\1\2\2\3\5\6,\40,0,DONE,1`